# Cuando envio correo por script bash no sale nada en el cuerpo de mensaje

Tags: bash

Tengo un problema y es que al enviar un contenido vía script en *bash*, cuando lo recibo por correo no sale nada y no entiendo lo que esta pasando. Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.

Saludos.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    echo $line
    ping -c 5 $line > /dev/null 2>&1

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Hay conexion"
    else
        echo "KO:" $line > enviar.txt
    fi
done < ip2.txt
ssmtp correo a enviar < enviar.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto es una suposición, pero por el script diría que todas las ips que tienes en `ip2.txt` funcionan y por eso no tienes nada en el mensaje.

Nótese que solo guardas en `enviar.txt` cuando una ip falla.
Otra cosa que he notado es que si 2 ip's fallan solo recibirás el KO de una de ellas.

`>` remplaza el fichero mientras que `>>` añade.

Por último si no hay un salto de línea en la última ip esta no será leída.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Eliminamos el fichero de la ejecución anterior
rm -f enviar.txt

# Nos aseguramos de leer la última linea
while IFS="" read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
  echo $line
  ping -c 5 $line >/dev/null 2>&1

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    # Agregamos el ok al fichero, esto quizá no quieras hacerlo pero no estaba seguro...
    echo "Hay conexion: $line" >> enviar.txt
  else
    # Agregamos el KO
    echo "KO:"$line >> enviar.txt
  fi 
done < ip2.txt

# Enviamos si el fichero existe. Útil si solo guardamos los KO's así solo recibiras el email cuando algo falle
if [ -f enviar.txt ]; then
  ssmtp correo a enviar < enviar.txt
fi
```

Comment: Ahora lo compruebo y te digo

Comment: Vale me funciona muchas Gracias!!